# There exists a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is not Lebesgue measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

From Mathematical Analysis by Andrew Browder;

[image]

In the last paragraph they said: for any $x \in [0,1)$,there exists $a \in A$ such that $x \sim a$ i.e. $x-a $ is rational ;then $x=a \bigoplus q$,where $q=x-a$or $q=x-a+1$ is a rational in $[0,1)$.I am unable to show this.

I know: for any $x \in [0,1)$,there exists $a \in A$ such that $x \sim a$ i.e. $x-a $ is rational. But how to show $x=a \bigoplus q$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For information these are called or based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x,y \in [0,1) $ implies that $x-a \in [-1,1)$. So $x-a \in [0,1)$ or $x-a \in [-1,0)$ and in the second case $x-a+1 \in [0,1)$.

Comment: I understood since $x \sim a$ $\implies$ $x-a \in \mathbb{Q}$. we have two cases either $x-a \in [0,1)$ or $x-a \in [-1,0)$ In first case $x-a=q$ is the rational number in $[0,1)$ but for second case,since $x-a \notin [0,1)$,we take the required rational number as $x-a+1 \in [0,1)$.For  first case we can write  $x=a+q$,and since $a+q<1$ we can write $x=a \bigoplus q$ But I am unable to prove for other case that $x=a \bigoplus q$,since there need  $a+q \geq 1$How should I show that?

Comment: Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @mathstudent In the second case $q=x-a+1$ is a rational number in  $[0,1)$. Now $x=a+q-1$ implies that $x=a\oplus q$ since $\oplus$ is addition modulo $1$.